# Compare minimax value with expectimax value

Tags: artificial-intelligence

If we have a game tree with the root node being a max node,with the minimax value of the tree as A,and another similar tree with the root node as a max node, but each min node is replaced with a chance node, with the expectimax value of the tree as E:is value A always smaller than or equal to E?

Comment: I am afraid that with this description, it would be very difficult - if not impossible - to help you with your problem. Could you please describe it a bit more? Some picture of the minimax tree demonstrating A and E values would also be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Let X_i be the random variable for the i-th node under the root.

It is clear that min(X_i) <= E(X_i), for every node i.

Now let j be the node chosen my the max root in the minimax tree:

max_i(min(X_i)) = min(X_j) <= E(X_j) <= max_i(E(X_i))

Therefore, A never greater than E.